# JQuery load(url) not working initially, activates after interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have am trying to make a page that get's loaded by Jquery into a div.
And it should be refreshed once in a while.

Now the refresh works.
However the initial page load does not.

I have tried to make sure I have written the correct code.
Could anyone point me in the correct direction?

The code that I have :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {


                    $.ajaxSetup({
                        cache: false
                    }); // This part addresses an IE bug. without it, IE will only load the first number and will never refresh
                    setInterval(function() {
                        $('#WebsiteImages').load('/images/?SetAjaxCall=loadimages');
                    }, 2000); // the "3000" here refers to the time to refresh the div. it is in milliseconds.

                    /// **** DEFAULT LOADING
                    //$('#WebsiteImages').html('Some set text :-)');
                    $('#WebsiteImages').load('/images/?SetAjaxCall=loadimages');

      });
   </script>
```

The div :

```
<div id="WebsiteImages"></div>
```

The strange part is, when uncommenting the :

```
$('#WebsiteImages').html('Some set text :-)');
```

That DOES work.

**EDIT**
I have tried the following code:

And the result is the same.
(* tried to set an alert as test and the code runs, -> I get the alert so no parse errors *)

```
$(window).load(function() {     
    $('#WebsiteImages').load('images/?SetAjaxCall=loadimages');          
});
```

I have also tried to make a function that loads right after the page load :

```
function LoadImagePage(){
                            $('#WebsiteImages').load(\'/images/?SetAjaxCall=loadimages');
                        }
```

Also added an alert to check if it has been loaded. And it runs. However to no avail.

**ANSWER**
By : *lshettyl*
The following code WORKED!!!

```
$(function() {

    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });

    //IIFE
    (function loadStuff() {
        $('#WebsiteImages').load('/images/?SetAjaxCall=loadimages', function() {
            setTimeout(loadStuff, 2000);
        });
    }());
});
```

Comment: Any error logged in the console?

Comment: Firebug -> console -> 0 errors :-(

Comment: Have you tried using $(window).load instead of document ready?

Comment: Why not make a IIFE instead of repeating the same lines of code, which is cleaner and less code? You may also use setTimeout within the load callback.

Comment: @Ishettyl you mean a function that loads at page load?

Comment: @AlexHakkenberg, in [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q5axXfOxsmyyF8olqtcF?p=preview) all seems work, first request to `default` and only then `interval` can you fix this plunkr to reproduce your error?

Comment: @AlexHakkenberg, also, is this possibly that first request to `/images/?SetAjaxCall=loadimages` return nothing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in my comments, it'd be cleaner to have an [`IIFE`](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) instead of repeating the code. I would also recommend using `setTimeout` within the callback of load as opposed to `setInterval`. Below is an example of what I said. Bear in mind that the code you already have should work unless these is a severe delay in the first call and setInterval would have already kicked in.

```
$(function() {

    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });

    //IIFE
    (function loadStuff() {
        $('#WebsiteImages').load('/images/?SetAjaxCall=loadimages', function() {
            setTimeout(loadStuff, 2000);
        });
    }());
});
```

Here is [**a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qqywpyn3/) along the same lines.

Comment: why you recommend using `setTimout` within callback instead `serInterval`?

Comment: `serInterval` is like a blind horse, as it just keeps running whether or not the `load` has actually finished as opposed to `setTimout` which would actually wait for the `load` to finish before it fires up again!.

Comment: Just tried this solution. Thank you for your lesson.